# How to stop a Blazor application on IIS?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor-webassembly

I have a IIS server running in a Windows 10 machine. On this IIS I hosted a **ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly** application. The app works fine!

The nightmare begins when I need to stop or disable the app. Nothing works for me!

I already tried to remove app from IIS (using the option "remove" from IIS context menu), stop application pool, restart website, restart IIS, even restart the server. The app stills running.

The only way that works was to delete app folder in Windows Explorer.

Please, someone knows what could be happining?

Comment: If you read a little more about WebAssembly, you will know that apps upon it are running inside the browser. Therefore, even if the network is disconnected, such apps can continue to run in a browser from local cache. Even what you described "The only way that works was to delete app folder in Windows Explorer" does not really work in some scenarios. If that's not what you wanted you should consider Blazor Server.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I'm aware about this Web Assembly behavior. Even cleaning browser cache the app stills running... I just forgot to mention it in my question.

Comment: Then it is rather interesting on what you have debugged. The browser developer tools should reveal very much everything to you, as well as IIS failed request tracing if you turn it on.

Comment: Unfortunately, the browser's devtools has no clue, not even a Javascript error in the console. It is as if the application remained active on the server, even after being deactivated in IIS. Any client, even those who never access the app, can load it. I'll try with IIS request tracking, as you suggested.

Comment: Did you get any useful information by using IIS request tracing?

Comment: Nothing useful. The mystery remains.

Comment: If you find any other way besides deleting the application folder in Windows Explorer, please come and share it here.